# Flutter DocumentSnapshot - Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Tags: flutter, snapshot

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: usersRef.doc(post.userId).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data;
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(snap.data()!);
```

Hello, all!
The 'snapshot.data' is giving me the above error. Please, help! Thanks!

Comment: Write like this  `DocumentSnapshot  snap = snapshot.data as  DocumentSnapshot ;`

Comment: oh... that was easy! lol thanks, @Problematic Dude!

Comment: does it Worked ?

Comment: the error is gone. but am stuck on a different issue. not yet checked... but, thanks anyways!

Comment: In that case I'm adding above comment as an answer. Mark it if error in the question is gone

Answer (score 3):

Do `DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;`